# how to trace this computed CSS value in firefox inspector?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am new to using Firefox's developer tools.

I am trying to make sense of why I have so far been unable to override the height of a given element. This page uses Bootstrap, but my question is not related to this particular issue: **I want to understand how, based on the information in the "Rules" and "Computed" panes, I could have diagnosed what the issue is.**

I am trying to set this element's height to 20px, but it remains at 90px (as shown in the second screenshot below) computed height of 90px.

**SCREENSHOT #1:**

[image]

**SCREENSHOT #2:**

[image]

**QUESTION: How can I use Firefox's Inspector to figure out what is going on here? How can I use it to figure out how this value of 90px is being derived?**

**Code inside the element:**

```
<span class="lang_pt" style="display: none;">O que fazemos</span>
<span class="lang_en" style="display: inline;">What we do</span>
```

PS: I don't write CSS so reliant on !important, I am trying to figure out what is happening here.

Comment: Are you using a framework that might attach that css value to that particular element?  Is it part of the html code itself?  It doesn't look like it was added in via a `.css` file, so I'm guessing it has to be either of those two options.

Comment: [Some reading material](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_CSS) for you. But just for reference, that `element` means it was written inline.

Comment: What is inside that anchor tag?

Comment: @ms_nitrogen, I am using boostrap.

Comment: @pol, thanks but that "element" line actually shows height: 20px, so I don't think it explains the 90px computed height?

Comment: Technically, you can't use the inspector to work out exactly how the computed height is derived. It depends in part on the font metrics, which the inspector doesn't show you. But the essence of the correct answer is given by Pat.

Comment: There is a bunch of CSS properties that won't apply depending on the element they are set on. It would be very useful if DevTools told you about those. This is being discussed in this bug for FirefoxDevTools: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303833

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as !important in the style= attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of an inline element is set strictly by its contents. Add `display: inline-block;` to the anchor so it will respect your `height: 20px;`